# BeanPropertyRowMapper throws org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException although setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue(true)

Tags: java, spring-batch

In my Spring Batch application I read a database table and map it to a dto. My dto has some fields of type `boolean`.

My Dto and the dao method look like following:

```
public class MyDto {

    private long id;
    private String yyy;
    private boolean xxx;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getYyy() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setYyy(String yyy) {
        this.yyy = yyy;
    }

    public boolean getXxx() {
        return xxx;
    }

    public void setXxx(boolean xxx) {
        this.xxx = xxx;
    }
}

@Override
public MyDto readMyDto(String id) {  
    SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource(ID, id);
    BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyDto > rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(MyDto.class);
    rowMapper.setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue(true);
    try {
        return this.jdbcTemplateStpl.queryForObject(LESE_KRAFTST_STEUERFALL, paramMap, rowMapper);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [null] to required type [boolean] for property 'xxx'` although I have set `setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue` to `true`.

In my UnitTests it works correct, even with the exception. When I set `setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue` to `false`, the tests will fail as expected with `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [null] to required type [boolean] for property 'xxx'.`

Is this exception with `setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue` set to `true`an error on my side or Spring Batch or is this behaviour expected and BeanPropertyRowMapper catches the exception and defaults null to false in this case (boolean)?

Comment: Your setter for `xxx` is incorrect, see @mansi 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Your method..  
public void setId(boolean xxx) {
        this.xxx = xxx;
    }

should be
public void setXxx(boolean xxx) {
        this.xxx = xxx;
    }
```

Comment: Thank your for the hint. That is a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: No, this was only a typo in the dto which happened because I changed the names of the variables to make it anonymous.